# Https URL does not launch when hosting ASP.NET CORE 2.1 project as Windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created a project in ASP.NET CORE 2.1 and hosted that project as Windows service.I have followed the instructions from the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.1.
After starting the service I have queried the State of the service.It is in running state.But if I browse the path in brwser that is specified in the "Enable SSL" property,url is not launching.
Or Am I using the wrong URL to browse the app?
The code I am using is

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsService();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseContentRoot(Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName))
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

Please guide me which URL I should use to launch the Windows service in browser or what mistake I am doing....

Comment: We don't see your configuration and how you deployed the service but `netstat -a` should tell you everything about open connections.

Comment: Try to use "http://localhost:5000" path to access service. they have used as default port. Ready point 7 from your given link

Comment: I have to run the Windows service in HTTPS.Fo that I have used app.UseHttpsRedirection() and configuredb the port to 5001.But that port is not in working."Page does not exists" error comes.May i know the solution for this.

Comment: As I said, check the list of open listening ports.